# iOS Charts compilation error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charts, ios-charts

I'm trying to develop an application that uses bar charts by using `iOS Charts`. I just set up `cocoapods` file, imported the `Charts.framework` and compiled the project, and I got the following error:

> /Users/i3t/Desktop/AppAdmin/eCardFidAdmin/Pods/Charts/Source/Charts/Utils/ChartPlatform.swift:111:30: Method does not override any method from its superclass

This error is happening in this function:

```
public final override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSUITouch>, withEvent event: NSUIEvent?)
{
    self.nsuiTouchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

I remove the override statement and I got this new error:

> /Users/i3t/Desktop/AppAdmin/eCardFidAdmin/Pods/Charts/Source/Charts/Utils/ChartPlatform.swift:111:21: Method 'touchesCancelled(*:withEvent:)' with Objective-C selector 'touchesCancelled:withEvent:' conflicts with method 'touchesCancelled(*:withEvent:)' from superclass 'UIResponder' with the same Objective-C selector

Someone knows how can I fix that?

Comment: Assuming this is Swift 3 the signature was changed to `with event:` instead of `withEvent event:`

Comment: Does not work yet. It is strange, the other functions has no problems, just the function "touchesCancelled"

Answer (score 0):

You are not subclassing it properly
use

```
import Charts
```

Your class has to be subclassed from  ChartPlatform

You can only override if you are subclassing otherwise it wont work

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But I do not understood. What class are you talking about when you say "Your class"? As I said, I do not change anything in my code, just imported the Chart.framework. Could you explain better?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I fixed it changing the parameter touches: as an optional like its parent function. (swift 2.2)

```
public final override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSUITouch>?, withEvent event: NSUIEvent?)
    {
        self.nsuiTouchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
```